# PromQL query to get the maximum of two metrics

Tags: max, prometheus, promql

In a Prometheus timeseries database, there are two sets of data (for M1 and M2) collected with following schema

- <timestamp>, <M1> <Labels L1, L2, L3>
- <timestamp>, <M2> <Labels L1, L2, L3, L4>

Write a PromQL query that creates a new time-series N,  that tracks the max(M1, M2) for each time period the query is run.

For example:
[image: table]

I tried using max(), but it takes only 1 argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PromQL](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) allows selecting time series with multiple different names via regexp filter on `__name__` pseudo-label. See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors). For example, the following query selects all the series with names `m1` and `m2`:

```
{__name__=~"m1|m2"}
```

So, the following query would select the max values over all the series with names `m1` and `m2` per each requested timestamp:

```
max({__name__=~"m1|m2"})
```

See the following additional info:

- [/api/v1/query docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries)
- [/api/v1/query_range docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#range-queries)

Comment: This is a nice workaround. The only case I see it is not applicable is when you need to do filtering based on a label not present in one of the metrics (e.g. you want to filter on label L4 value of M2 from the original question).

Comment: @Nikola, this is possible, with some limitations. For example if `m2` is guaranteed to have `l4`, and `m1` is not, you can use `{__name__=~"m1|m2", l4=~"l4value|"}`. It will match metrics with `l4` equal to `l4value`, or `l4` missing (missing labels are equal to empty string)

Comment: It is also possible with [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/), which supports `or` inside curly braces: `{__name__="metric1",label="some_value" or __name__="metric2"}` selects series with `metric1` name and `label="some_value"` label, plus all the series with `metric2` name

Answer (score 5):

If `metric1` and `metric2` have different label sets (as declared in question) or have different label values, you can use

```
max(metric1 OR metric2)
```

Here `or` will produce union of metrics `metric1` and `metric2`, somewhat similarly to what `UNION` does in SQL.

---

Please notice that this approach cannot be used for metrics with matching labels, as dataset cannot contain two time series with same labels.

Comment: I gave this a try but it always takes metric1 value as the output. "OR" doesn't check the metric2 value at all.

Comment: If they have a different set of labels (like you have said in the question) the OR will use both. Take a look at the "OR" operator in Prometheus documentation here: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators

Answer (score 2):

```
metric1 > metric2 or metric2 > metric1
```

I think this does the max and works also when both metrics have the same set of labels.

Comment: This answer only helped me, thanks! I think `metric1 > metric2 or metric2` would give the same result

Comment: What if `metric1 == metric2`?

Comment: This solution would work **only** if metrics have the same labels. Otherwise `metric1 > metric2` will not yield any result. And yes, `> metric1` is not only redundant, it would cause issues for equal metrics.